# Shift/reduce conflict with expression call

Tags: parsing, grammar, shift-reduce-conflict, lemon

When I'm trying to compile this simple parser using Lemon, I get a conflict but I can't see which rule is wrong. The conflict disappear if I remove the binaryexpression or the callexpression.

```
%left Add.

program ::= expression.

expression ::= binaryexpression.
expression ::= callexpression.

binaryexpression ::= expression Add expression.

callexpression ::= expression arguments.

arguments ::= LParenthesis argumentlist RParenthesis.
arguments ::= LParenthesis RParenthesis.

argumentlist ::= expression argumentlist.
argumentlist ::= expression.
```

**[edit]** Adding a left-side associativity to LParenthesis has solved the conflict.
However, I'm willing to know if it's the correct thing to do : I've seen that some grammars (f.e. C++) have a different precedence for the construction-operator '()' and the call-operator '()'. So I'm not sure about the right thing to do.

Comment: Is your grammar complete? Because at the moment it defines the empty language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the grammar is ambiguous. It is not possible to decide between reducing to `binaryexpression` or `callexpression` without looking at all the input sequence. The ambiguity is because of the left recursion over `expression`, which cannot be ended because `expression` cannot derive a terminal.